# Save total order items volume of WooCommerce orders as custom meta data

Tags: php, wordpress, object, woocommerce, orders

I need to calculate the volume of single order, and store the totale result in the DB to then retrieve it trough the Rest Api and access this parameter there.
i tried to write it down something, but in the checkout i get Internal server error.

This is what I am trying to do *(in my imagination)*:

```
// Store volume in the database
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'woo_add_cart_volume');

function woo_add_cart_volume( $order_id ) {
    $order        = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // <== Was missing
    $total_volume = 0; // Initializing variable

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        $product = $item['data'];
        $qty     = $item['quantity'];

        // Get product dimensions  
        $length = $product->get_length();
        $width  = $product->get_width();
        $height = $product->get_height();

        // Calculations a item level
        $total_volume += $length * $width * $height * $qty;
    }
    
    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_item_volume', $total_volume );
}
```

Thanks for you precious help be patient with me. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should suffice, to store the total volume in the `wp_postmeta` table.

- `$product = $item['data'];` is not correct, causing you to get the following error further in the code `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_length() on null`. Use `$product = $item->get_product();` instead
- Additional explanation via comment tags added in the code

```php
// Store total volume in the database (wp_postmeta table)
function action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    // Get $order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    // Is a WC_Order
    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        // Initializing variable
        $total_volume = 0;
        
        // Loop through order items
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            // Get product object
            $product = $item->get_product();
            
            // Get quantity
            $qty = $item->get_quantity();

            // Get product dimensions  
            $length = $product->get_length();
            $width  = $product->get_width();
            $height = $product->get_height();

            // Calculations a item level
            $total_volume += $length * $width * $height * $qty;
        }
        
        // Store in wp_postmeta table
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_item_volume', $total_volume );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first save each order item volume as custom order item meta data, with the following:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'woo_order_item_volume', 10, 4 );
function woo_order_item_volume( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $product = $values['data'];
    $qty     = $values['quantity'];

    $length = $product->get_length();
    $width  = $product->get_width();
    $height = $product->get_height();

    $item->update_meta_data( '_volume', $length * $width * $height * $qty ); // Save item volume
}
```

Then you save the order total volume as order meta data as follows:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'woo_order_total_volume');
function woo_order_total_volume( $order ) {
    $total_volume = 0; // Initializing

    // Loop through order items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        $total_volume += $item->get_meta( '_volume' ); // Add item volume to total
    }
    $order->update_meta_data( '_total_volume', $total_volume ); // Save total volume for order
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.